# How to run pure java code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am used to Android Studio and don't want to use other ide for Java development. How do I run pure java in Android Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this post](https://medium.com/@droid.dev/code-pure-java-in-android-studio-e794a257825).

In main menu-bar, go to File -> New -> New Module

[image]

Now scroll down to the bottom and select Java Library in the window that pops up

[image]

click next and set the package name in next screen

[image]

Click Finish. Android Studio will create Java Library Module for you. You are ready to code. All the short-cuts, key-mappings, auto-complete and scaffolding of IntelliJ platform is available for you to speed up your coding.

You can find your newly created Java Library in the Android scope in Project Navigator

[image]

You can add as many classes and packages you need.

[image: Scaffolding]

Enter psvm (short for public static void main) and press enter to create your main method.

Once the method is created you will see green play button next to method and class to allow you to run your program.

[image]

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Hi, This method didn't work on Android Studio 4.2